# Android Studio does not let me compile a specific project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android project ran just perfectly 2 days ago ,but  today i added some code in it and I put a file in my assets folder and now Android Studio doesn't let me compile it.

Refer to the image below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJf2g.png

I've tried to rebuild it but nothing changed. 
This is my very first post here , so i am sorry if i did something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some more detailed information about changes that have occurred recently. Newly updated packages and toolchain components can turn a previously fine project into a swingset with the wrong bolts included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check your run configuration: 
[image]

If there is no configuration, create a new one with "New -> Android App".

Then you can also go to your MainActivity, right-click it and choose "Run MainActivity".

Comment: Thank you sir . Worked perfectly

Comment: Great :) You can then btw accept my answer (under the votes, there is a button) so that others can see it solved the problem.

Comment: I will . But it says i have to wait ~ 5 minutes  but not a problem. Thanks again

Comment: just said it because you pointed out that you are new to this site. so yeah thanks! ^^